# Azure RemoteApp - Run IE9 and JRE

Tags: azure, cloud, rdp, remoteapp

Does RemoteApp allow you to install any version of Internet Explorer? I have a need to support 40 users and I need to give them access to IE9 and a specific version of Java Run Time.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Azure RemoteApp uses **images** to hold the apps that you share with your users.

To create an Azure RemoteApp collection with your choice of applications, whether it is cloud or hybrid, you start by creating an image with those applications installed.

Then, create a collection that uses that image, assign users to the collection, and publish apps to those users.

Thus, you can create a custom Azure RemoteApp image with Internet Explorer 9 and also the specific JDK version to meet your requirements.

Hope this helps!

Reference: [Create an Azure RemoteApp image](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-imageoptions/)